# Prove the Identity $\frac{2\pi}{N}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-N}^{N} \left(1-\frac{\xi}{N}\right)e^{i \xi t}d\xi dt=1$

Tags: fourier-transform

Does anyone know what the best approach for this integral identity is? $$ \frac{2\pi}{N}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-N}^{N} \left(1-\frac{\xi}{N}\right)e^{i \xi t}d\xi 
 dt=1,\quad \forall N \in \mathbb{R}, \quad N >0$$

Comment: It is not true, because your integral equals $\frac{8\pi\cdot\text{Si}\left(\text{N}\cdot\pi\right)}{\text{N}}$ Where $\text{Si}\left(x\right)$ is the sine integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp(i \xi t) \; dt = \frac{2\sin(\pi \xi)}{\xi} ,
$$
$$
I =\frac{4\pi}{N}\int_{-N}^N\left(1-\frac{\xi}{N}\right)\frac{\sin(\pi \xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi,
$$
by symmetry $\sin(\pi \xi)=-\sin(-\pi \xi)$ so one of the terms cancels to give
$$
I =\frac{4\pi}{N}\int_{-N}^N\frac{1}{\xi}\sin(\pi \xi) \; d\xi = \frac{8\pi}{N}\int_{0}^N\frac{\sin(\pi \xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi = \frac{8\pi}{N}\mathrm{Si}(\pi N),
$$
where $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ is the [Sine-integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function. The point where the original identity is true is at $N\approx39.487806651487979$.